# WPF subclass capturing key press event

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and am building a test application. In my application I have a user control that is calling another class to capture the fingerprint from the device. The class that captures the fingerprint from the device is running on a do while loop, that constantly keeps reading from the device. I want to introduce an event that can break the do while. In my user control I can capture the KeyDown event. But the class that is capturing the fingerprint is unable to capture the keypress. Any thing that I am missing on?

```
This is my Sample File.Xaml.cs code

   protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl || e.Key == Key.RightCtrl)
        {

        }
        else
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

 private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


            TNTFMT220 tntFmt220 = new TNTFMT220();
            string fingerPrintId = "";
            var data = tntFmt220.ContiniousCaptureFingerPrint(ref fingerPrintId);                          

    }
```

This is my code to capture the fingerprint

```
   public bool ContiniousCaptureFingerPrint(ref string FingerPrintScanned)
    {
      do
       {
         //get data from device
        }  while(dataReturned);
     return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UserControl is made by a window and a class, when the UserControl window is focused and you press a key, you can get a OnKeyDown event.

I think your `TNTFMT220` class has not a window, so you can generate the event in  UserControl or in Main Window and propagate it to the class in different ways, I suggest you a couple:

1. Class Property

   ```
   protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl || e.Key == Key.RightCtrl)
       {
           tntFmt220.doStop= true;
       }
       else
           base.OnKeyDown(e);
   }

   private TNTFMT220 tntFmt220;

   private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       tntFmt220 = new TNTFMT220();
       string fingerPrintId = "";
       var data = tntFmt220.ContiniousCaptureFingerPrint(ref fingerPrintId);
   }
   ```
2. Class Method

   ```
   protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl || e.Key == Key.RightCtrl)
       {
           tntFmt220.DoStop();
       }
       else
           base.OnKeyDown(e);
   }

   private TNTFMT220 tntFmt220;

   private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       tntFmt220 = new TNTFMT220();
       string fingerPrintId = "";
       var data = tntFmt220.ContiniousCaptureFingerPrint(ref fingerPrintId);

   }
   ```

Above all:

First of all, I probably think again if that `do while` is needed or if `TNTFMT220` can generate an event when data is read.

Then, if you don't want that `do While` will block you window, you have to run it in a different thread.

Comment: I Tried the above, but was getting the same issue. I will try the different thread approach. Thanks for the insight